# SSL connect error cannot send tlsv1.2

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Curl fails error
SSL connect error

Server Open SSL version:
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon May  9 07:30:30 CDT 2016

Server curl -V:
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.6.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2

curl code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->config_proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/xml', 'Expect: '));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->config_timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

is there any possible way to run this curl, without updating curl version on server, because my client recommands not to update curl version on server

Comment: I tried all options given in answers of similar question, but none worked with my case.

Answer (score 0):

It's the SSL handshake, what does your webserver's log say ?
You could use a stream context and set it to use all ciphers, like this:

```
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            // set some SSL/TLS specific options
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'ciphers' => 'ALL'
        )
    ));
```

Alternatively, you could try to set the SSL cipher list in curl, e.g.:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA');
```

Comment: Tried without proxy too, 
server says same error, SSL connect error, HTTP response code 0

Comment: That could mean that the SSL handshake is failing. Are you able to connect to other pages, like https://www.google.com ? You should have an error message for the SSL handshake error in your webserver's logfile (e.g. Apache log). Can you post the error from the log pls ?

Comment: yes many other curl are running fine, so i am sure problem is in SSL handshake,  & sorry i can't find Apache error logs on server.

Comment: The apache error log file can be found at /var/log/apache2/error.log or in a different path, depending on your vhost configuration. I had the same problem in september last year, and the real problem was that the server forced a cipher that has been disabled by default in the new PHP version. So the fix was to enable the needed cipher. You could try by enabling all cyphers and remove one by one.

Comment: using curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA') didn't worked

Answer (score -1):

This problem happened when you are trying access URL that is secure page(https://).

try this.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

It is working in my case.

Comment: This is not a solution, you are trying to turn off the Certificate verification, it will only help in case server is using self signed certificate and you want to bypass the certificate verification. This setup is not recommended in production until unless you trust the server you are trying to connect by yourself (like when it is your own server).